# Some VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, MATCH and INDEX combination which can pull the data from tables in different format into one summary sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want some VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, MATCH and INDEX combination which can pull the data from tables in different format into one summary sheet. One of the tables is in this format:

`Name       Date       Scores`
`Sam        1 jan      23`
`Aron       1 jan      27`
`Alicia     1 jan      21`
`Sam        2 jan      24`
`Aron       2 jan      26`
`Alicia     2 jan      29`
`Sam        3 jan      20`
`Aron       3 jan      20`
`Alicia     3 jan      21`

Other table is in this format:

`name   1 mar   2 mar   3 mar   4 mar   5 mar`
`Sam    P       A       P       P       P`
`Aron   P       P       P       A       P`
`Alicia P       A       P       P       P`

I want to create a summary sheet where I can pull the data from both the sheets accordingly like this:

Name   **Aron**

`Date   Attendance   Marks`
`1 jan  P            27`
`2 jan  P            26`
`3 jan  P            20`

I figured out the attendance sheet. I am using VLOOKUP and MATCH combination.
However, I am experiencing issues pulling out the data from the first table. I can't figure out what formula to use.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the `SUMPRODUCT()` function - [Here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) is a good explanation

to summarise your problem you want to find out:

1. which cells in column A of the `Scores` sheet have text "Aron"

   ```
   --> IF(A2:A20!`Scores`="Aron")
   ```
2. which cells in column B of the `Scores` sheet contain date the same as in cell `A4!Summary`

   ```
   --> IF(B2:B20!`Scores`=A4!Summary)
   ```
3. where 1. IS `TRUE` and 2. IS `TRUE`, get the cell value in corresponding row of column C

   ```
   --> =SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2:A20!`Scores`="Aron",1,0)*IF(B2:B20!`Scores`=A4!Summary,1,0)*C2:C10!`Scores`)
   ```

---

BE CAREFUL if it is possible that more than one row matches. This will return the SUM of the matching values

ALSO: if you used google Sheets instead you could simply use the [FILTER() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason why there 2 tables used ?

If not, try using something like this:

```
Name    Date    Scores  Attendance
Sam     1 jan   23      P
Aron    1 jan   27      P 
Alicia  1 jan   21      P
Sam     2 jan   24      A
Aron    2 jan   26      P
Alicia  2 jan   29      A
Sam     3 jan   20      P
Aron    3 jan   20      P
Alicia  3 jan   21      P
```

and then create Pivot Table to get desired result ?

Let me know, if that works for you.

Thanks.

M.

Comment: Tables are downloaded from different tools therefore I need a solution with these particular tables only